# Nodejs установка express

Tags: node.js, express

Здравствуйте, изучая node.js, по [этой статье](http://frontender.info/absolute-beginners-guide-to-nodejs/#yaustanovilnodechtotepery) столкнулся с некоторыми затруднениями, 
Вроде бы все начал понимать, но в разделе "Делаем что-нибудь полезное — Express" не понял как установить модуль express. `cd /my/app/location` - что это за директория должна быть? Как я понял для установки модуля нужно набрать команду `npm install express` (это понятно) но перед этим, я тaк понял, нужно перейти в какую-то директорию... Подправьте меня, и направьте в правильном направлении! Заранее благодарен!

Comment: Директория вашего проекта. Какая у вас ось?

Comment: подопытный файл просто пока разместил на C:/ 
Ось - Windows 7

Comment: создайте  директорию где-нибудь, npm вы уже установили ?

Comment: Нужно добавить путь до npm и node в список глобальных переменных среды и потом установить экспресс в папку с проектом.

Comment: Будьте добры, напишите пожалуйста примерчик, как добавить пути и как установить экспресс!

Comment: а разве npm нужно устанавливать? в статье вроде бы написано: Вместе с командой node у вас появилась команда npm

Comment: Почитайте эту переписку http://vk.com/wall-21042144_3638 Возможно, она вам поможет

Comment: Нет, не помогло, там в переписке решался вопрос, с которым я разобрался. Мне нужно узнать, как  устанавливать плагины, какие пути прописывать, и т. д.

Comment: @Deathdrumer http://shapeshed.com/creating-a-basic-site-with-node-and-express/ и https://github.com/shapeshed/express_example
могут помочь эти ссылки

Answer (score 3):

> как устанавливать плагины

npm i module_name

> какие пути прописывать

Папка, где лежат файлы вашего проекта.

Создайте папку hello  в моих документах. Убедитесь, что у вас установлены node.js, npm, и [express-generator](https://github.com/expressjs/generator). Перейдите, в консоле, в папку test и выполните `express && npm i` в консоле. Дальше по тексту статьи, что вы нашли.

Comment: Такое впечатление, что это никогда не кончится: устанавливаешь одно, потом выясняется, что нужно установить еще что-то. Я думал, что нужен nodejs с помощью которого я установлю express, но оказалось, что нужен какой-то express-generator!!! Что за лабиринт!

Comment: `express-generator` появился с 4 версии. Он отнюдь не обязателен, но для удобства пусть будет. Заодно и модули глобально устанавливать потренируетесь. Его появление вызвано тем, насколько я понимаю, что бы ядро фреймворка разрабатывалось особняком, а все middleware-ы и прочие плюшки отдельно.

Comment: Ребят, добавьте меня кто-нить в скайп, логин youbiznes Помогите кто-нибудь уже наконец! В благодарность пару сотен закину на кошелек.

Comment: @Deathdrumer, это не фриланс биржа. Что у вас не получается? В консоле  есть команды node и npm?

Comment: У меня выходит в терминале таблица, не могу ее сюда скопировать, я тут вообще очень ограничен в написании... Очень трудно объяснить, по-моему у нас недопонимание и поэтому уже второй день я как тупица не могу разобраться с этим, хотя, наверняка тут все просто... Хотя, что-то вроде бы получилось!

Comment: если вывод сильно большой - воспользуйтесь pastebin

Comment: вот опять же, куда вставлять этот pastebin, что с ним делать, непонятно. В общем сложность с установкой socket.io возникла, выдает ошибки, типа загрузка компонента visual C++ невозможно, установите .NET framework. Установил этот фреймворк и ничего не изменилось, все тоже самое

Comment: ну я вам говорил - linux проще. к сожалению в винде не помогу, ничего с ней кроме сноса не делал уже лет 10

Answer (score 0):

Статья по ссылке в вопросе - не лучший вариант для начинающего.
[Рекомендую вот это.](http://nodebeginner.ru/)
И в Экспресс на данном этапе изучения рекомендую вообще не трогать. Пока не трогать. Вернуться к нему когда будет понимание основных процессов.

Answer (score 0):

Если вы попали на эту страницу, и не знаете как устанавливать модули из руководств найденых в интернете... Немножко длинное объяснение.

После установки дистрибутива под Windows c [официального сайта](https://nodejs.org/en/download/) вам надо проверить результат.

Зайдите в командную строку Windows. Искать тут:

```
Пуск - Все программы - Стандартные - Командная строка
```

Наберите в ней:

```
node -v
```

Нажмите enter. Результатом должно быть что-то вроде:

```
v4.1.2
```

Теперь наберием

```
npm version
```

Жмем enter. Должны увидеть что-то вроде:

```
{ npm: '2.14.4',
ares: '1.10.1-DEV',
http_parser: '2.5.0',
modules: '46',
node: '4.1.2',
openssl: '1.0.2d',
uv: '1.7.5',
v8: '4.5.103.35',
zlib: '1.2.8' }
```

Если у вас это работает. То исполнив:

```
npm install express
```

Вы сможете себе поставить модуль express на компьютер.

Answer (score 0):

ну давайте по порядку.

1. `cd /my/app/location`: если в вкратце то `cd` - это команда для терминала windows которая позволяет, перемещаться между директориями.

1.2. `/my/app/...` путь в который нам нужно перейти, условно это то же самое что подключение стилей css к html когда вы в `link herf='<вписываете сюда свою ссылку, относительно данного файла>'`,

1.3

> что это за директория должна быть?

директорию вы создаете сами, те это просто заготовленная папка, в которой лежат ваши проекты например, я зашел в документы и создал там папку `Project` и в уже в ней я создал папку `express`

что бы перейти в данную папку, я буду использовать команду `cd Documents/Project/express`

1.4 вот ссылка на [информацию о команде cd](https://ab57.ru/cmdlist/cd.html): `https://ab57.ru/cmdlist/cd.html`

2. С каталогами разобрались теперь с установкой nodejs и express, для того что бы установить сам экспресс сперва нужно инициализировать nodejs, для этого в командной строке в которой мы прописывали пути, пишем команду `npm init -y`, флаг `-y` позволит не заполнять различную информацию о проекте, после чего прописываем `npm i express` и все, можете творить.

Так же что бы проверить установлен ли `express` или нет, достаточно просто посмотреть файл `package.json` в нем ищем раздел `dependencies`, в котором написаны все установленные вами библиотеки.

Надеюсь помог и нигде не ошибся, спасибо за внимание)